# Pinging hostnames takes too long (vs Pinging IP addresses)

Tags: c#, networking, ping

I'm using async Ping to check if remote computers are available or not (**code sample** from [here](http://justinmklam.com/posts/2018/02/ping-sweeper/#third-attempt-one-ping-to-rule-them-all-one-ping-to-find-them)). I modified it to use a List instead of a IP range.

This works great **IF** input is a list of IP addresses (0,5 seconds for 300+ hosts). But i need to check a list of hostnames and that takes to long (30+ seconds for 300+ hosts).

Problem seems to be DNS name resolving for unavailable hosts. Is there a way to get around it?

Or maybe a different way to check if computers are online (but it has to use list of host names as input).

EDIT: I used code from his 3rd attempt, that's why i linked directly to that section of the page. I probably should have made that clearer

Comment: That's why i linked to specific section on the page. 
Figured its better than to just say "i used 3rd attempt" :)

Comment: Ah so you did, goodo

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the IP address for the host-names will necessarily take more time than having the IP directly.

Options include:

1. Performing the pings in parallel. The code sample you linked to shows how to do this, but make sure you're using the code under section 3 "Third Attempt: One Ping to Rule Them All, One Ping to Find Them", instead of one of the earlier patterns, in case you're not already.
2. I'm going to take a guess that you're doing this ping repetitively. If this is the case, then do the DNS lookups once at the start, and then from that point on you can ping the IP addresses. For example with [Dns.GetHostAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I do use parallel (i edited original post).
Not sure what you mean by repetitively, but i am using it once every app launch to filter out offline host from a list. I generate all sorts of different reports on computers and those offline hosts are really slowing down my app.
I dont use any database to store hosts and app doesnt run in the background.
I just need a list of online hosts in that moment so i can work with it.

Resolving names "manually" with getHost and converting it back to host name (output should be host names) is even slower than just letting Ping function do it by itself.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote code below back in March.  I have a 12 second timeout for all the pings to complete.  The code will finish quicker if all the pings complete.  I also use a datatable for my list of pings and the ping response also goes into the table so you can get the time of each ping and the status (completed or failed).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("IP", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TimeOut", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Canceled", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("Error", typeof(List<string>));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reply", typeof(List<PingReply>));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sent", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Received", typeof(int));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "192.168.1.1", 0, false, null, null, 4, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "172.160.1.27", 0, false, null, null, 4, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "172.160.1.37", 0, false, null, null, 4, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "172.160.1.57", 0, false, null, null, 4, 0 });


            MyPing ping = new MyPing(dt);

            List<PingReply> replies = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<List<PingReply>>("Reply") != null).Select(x => x.Field<List<PingReply>>("Reply")).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

            long ShortTime = replies.Min(x => x.RoundtripTime);
        }
    }

    public class MyPing
    {
        static AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        const string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        private Object thisLock = new Object();

        DataTable dt;
        Dictionary<string, DataRow> pingDict = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>();
        const int TIMEOUT = 12000;
        public MyPing() { }
        public MyPing(DataTable dtin)
        {
            dt = dtin;

            Console.WriteLine("Haciendo ping a los equipos, no cierre esta ventana... ");



            // Por cada IP se realiza ping y se  agrega a la lista del modelo
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                string ip = item.Field<string>("IP");
                pingDict.Add(ip, item);
                ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                PingOptions pingoptns = new PingOptions(128, true);
                Console.WriteLine("send : {0}", ip);
                ping.SendAsync(ip, TIMEOUT, buffer, pingoptns, item);
            }

            waiter.WaitOne();
        }
        private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {

                DataRow row = null;
                try
                {
                    row = e.UserState as DataRow;
                    string sendIP = row.Field<string>("IP");
                    string replyIP = e.Reply.Address.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("reply IP : {0}, send IP : {1}", replyIP, sendIP);
                    // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user.
                    if (e.Cancelled)
                    {
                        row.SetField<bool>("Canceled", true);
                        return;
                    }

                    // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user.
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        if (row["Error"] == DBNull.Value) row["Error"] = new List<string>();
                        row.Field<List<string>>("Error").Add(e.Error.Message);
                    }
                    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
                    {
                        row["TimeOut"] = row.Field<int>("TimeOut") + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (row["Reply"] == DBNull.Value) row["Reply"] = new List<PingReply>();
                        row.Field<List<PingReply>>("Reply").Add(e.Reply);
                        row["Received"] = row.Field<int>("Received") + 1;
                    }

                    row["Sent"] = row.Field<int>("Sent") - 1;
                    if (row.Field<int>("Sent") > 0)
                    {
                        Ping ping = new Ping();
                        string ip = row.Field<string>("IP");
                        ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        PingOptions pingoptns = new PingOptions(128, true);
                        Console.WriteLine("send : {0}", ip);
                        ping.SendAsync(ip, TIMEOUT, buffer, pingoptns, row); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pingDict.Remove(sendIP);
                        if (pingDict.Count == 0) waiter.Set();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How does that address _"but it has to use list of hostnames as input"_?

Comment: Ping works with either IP address as a string, or hostname.

Comment: Yessss, but not sure how much different this is from the example. 
 Perhaps do a one-time lookup as Peter suggests?

Comment: The code does a lookup.  That is what the dictionary is used for.  Code can ping multiple times and when all response occurs the dictionary empties and then sets the AutoResetEvent to indicate the end.

Comment: I dont think this is what i need.  
I need to work with host names not IP addresses.  
My input is list of host names (online and offline) and my output should also be list of host names (online only).  
Ping does work with both IP and hostnames but its much slower using hostnames. Thats the problem here...

Comment: Using IP standard IP routing is used.  Using Computer name a request is made to the DNS Server to get route.  The speed really depends on get a reply from all hosts.  My code will finish in 12 seconds max because all the pings are done in parallel with a timeout.  When all the hosts reply the code should finish in less time. 
 The code you reference I don't think will do the same.

Comment: I dont agree that the speed depends on reply from host alone when using Computer Names. It depends on how fast DNS can resolve host name to IP before trying to ping it. I get response from 400+ clients in under 1 second when i use IP address. So resolving DNS names must be a problem.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If the host name is not found then you are waiting for a timeout to occur.  All the IP addresses are found and that is why you are completing quickly.  Add an IP address that doesn't exist and see how long the program takes to complete.

Comment: I did. I tested it in using an entire range of 192.168.1 and 192.168.2 from 1-255 (500+entries total). There were many IP not used (offline) and app still gets through all of them in under 1 second. As i said, pinging works amazing IF your input is IP address..

Comment: What timeout are you using?  100msec is too short for a response.  Make timeout 5 sec and see if you get a response using Hostname.